# Block automated responses in web form to AOL email adresses

Tags: php, forms

I have php contact form that sends an automated response once it is submitted. The problem that we are having is that when the recipient is @aol.com they are getting reported as spam to AOL. we would like to disable the automated response just for the @aol.com addresses

```
<?php
//Collect contact form data
//Check Special Field
//Email ASC & Webmaster
//Email Sender
//Redirect to thank you page

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.php');

/********  CONTACT DATA **********/
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$company = stripslashes($_POST['company']);
$address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
$city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$state = stripslashes($_POST['state']);
$zipcode = stripslashes($_POST['zipcode']);
$country = stripslashes($_POST['country']);
$website = $_POST['website'];
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$fax = stripslashes($_POST['fax']);
$email = stripslashes($_POST['contact']);
$Referred = stripslashes($_POST['referred']);
 $CustomerType = stripslashes($_POST['CustomerType']);
 $Comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);


 /********  CHECK SPECIAL FIELD **********/
 $spamcheck = stripslashes($_POST['email']);

//if spamcheck is blank complete page
 if ($spamcheck=="") {


/********  EMAIL ASC & WEBMASTER  **********/
$message = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$name has visited the Coastal web site and would like some information.
The details they entered on the website are:

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

Kind Regards,
Coastal Pet Products, Inc.
http://www.coastalpet.com
";   
 $email_address = "ashley.brindle@coastalpet.com, robert.kendall@coastalpet.com,    heather.hartman@coastalpet.com";    

$subject = "Information Inquiry";
$headers = "From: $name <$email>";
$message = str_replace("\r",'',$message); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages





/********  EMAIL SENDER **********/
$message2 = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Re: Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you $name for visiting the Coastal Pet Products web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

Kind Regards,
Coastal Pet Products, Inc
http://www.coastalpet.com
";   
$email_address2 = "$email";         
$subject2 = "Re: Information Inquiry";
$headers2 = "From: Coastal Pet Products <ashley.brindle@coastalpet.com>";
$message2 = str_replace("\r",'',$message2); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages

    //send message 1 and save result in success var (either true for success,
// or false for fail
$success = mail(mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message, $headers2) && mail($email_address, $subject, $message, $headers))

//conditionaly send message2, no need to check success on this one
if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) {
mail(mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2) && mail($email_address,   $subject, $message, $headers))
}

if ($success){
//show success message
 success
}
else{
//fail message
fail
}


?>
      <h3>Thank you for your interest in Coastal Pet Products!</h3>
      <p>If you have asked us to contact you, we will be using the information you provided. We thank you for taking the time to help us be a better company.</p>   

<?php } else { ?>
    <p>There was a problem submitting your information.  Please try again.</p>
    <p>If you continue to have problems, please contact Customer Service at 1-800-321-0248.</p>


<?php } 



?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to make an attempt first. Then, post your code and tell us specifically what's wrong. You'll get a lot more help if you show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) {
    //send auto response
}
```

To clarify:

```
//send message 1 and save result in success var (either true for success,
// or false for fail
$success = mail($message1 <SNIP>...

//conditionaly send message2, no need to check success on this one
if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) {
    mail($message2 <SNIP>...
}

if ($success){
//show success message
}else{
//fail message
}
```

EDIT 2
ok, so i think you need to read a good book on php, WROX books are usually well written.
Also use a half decent IDE, and it would highlight the more obvious errors for you.
JetBrains php storm is awesome, or if you dont want to pay, netbeans is pretty good.

That said, i have cleaned up you code for you here:

```
<?php
    //Collect contact form data
    //Check Special Field
    //Email ASC & Webmaster
    //Email Sender
    //Redirect to thank you page

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.php');

    /********  CONTACT DATA **********/
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $company = stripslashes($_POST['company']);
    $address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
    $city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
    $state = stripslashes($_POST['state']);
    $zipcode = stripslashes($_POST['zipcode']);
    $country = stripslashes($_POST['country']);
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $fax = stripslashes($_POST['fax']);
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['contact']);
    $Referred = stripslashes($_POST['referred']);
    $CustomerType = stripslashes($_POST['CustomerType']);
    $Comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);


    /********  CHECK SPECIAL FIELD **********/
    $spamcheck = stripslashes($_POST['email']);

    //if spamcheck isnt blank exit page, no need for error message to user, as its a spam bot
    if ($spamcheck!=="") {

        exit;

    }


        /********  EMAIL ASC & WEBMASTER  **********/
        $message = "
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Information Inquiry
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $name has visited the Coastal web site and would like some information.
    The details they entered on the website are:

    Name: $name
    Company: $company
    Address: $address
    City: $city
    State: $state
    Zip Code: $zipcode
    Country: $country
    Website: $website
    Phone: $phone
    Fax: $fax
    Email: $email

    Referred to web site: $Referred

    CustomerType: $CustomerType

    Comments: $Comments

    Kind Regards,
    Coastal Pet Products, Inc.
    http://www.coastalpet.com
    ";
        $email_address = "ashley.brindle@coastalpet.com, robert.kendall@coastalpet.com,    heather.hartman@coastalpet.com";

        $subject = "Information Inquiry";
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
        $message = str_replace("\r",'',$message); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages





        /********  EMAIL SENDER **********/
        $message2 = "
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Re: Information Inquiry
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Thank you $name for visiting the Coastal Pet Products web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.

    Name: $name
    Company: $company
    Address: $address
    City: $city
    State: $state
    Zip Code: $zipcode
    Country: $country
    Website: $website
    Phone: $phone
    Fax: $fax
    Email: $email

    Referred to web site: $Referred

    CustomerType: $CustomerType

    Comments: $Comments

    Kind Regards,
    Coastal Pet Products, Inc
    http://www.coastalpet.com
    ";
        $email_address2 = "$email";
        $subject2 = "Re: Information Inquiry";
        $headers2 = "From: Coastal Pet Products <ashley.brindle@coastalpet.com>";
        $message2 = str_replace("\r",'',$message2); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages

    //send message 1 and save result in success var (either true for success, or false for fail
    $success = mail($email_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

    //conditionally send message2, no need to check success on this one
    if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) {
        mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
    }

    if ($success):?>
          <h3>Thank you for your interest in Coastal Pet Products!</h3>
          <p>If you have asked us to contact you, we will be using the information you provided. We thank you for taking the time to help us be a better company.</p>

    <?php else:?>

        <p>There was a problem submitting your information.  Please try again.</p>
        <p>If you continue to have problems, please contact Customer Service at 1-800-321-0248.</p>
    <?php endif;?>
```

I havent checked this, but it should be fine.

Comment: I added if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) { $message2 = " and it executed the last else which is an error message but it does not send $message either I would prefer that it sends $message but not $message2.  Basically there is the $message and then$message2 is the confirmation back to the user. In the case of aol.com some users have settings in aol mail that reports it automatically as spam and we have been threatened with blacklist

Comment: @bobkendall This is why it was suggested that you show your code, but regardless, surely you can just wrap the above snippet around your message2 section?

Comment: I have added the source code to the original post.

Comment: if (mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2) && mail($email_address, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
 ?>    is the statement that actually sends the email $message and $message2 seem to executed together shouldn't I be able to just add if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) { above this section and then make the bottom an else?

Comment: Dont send them in the same line, send them seperatly, and base success/failure of of message1 (as long as you get the email, its a success)

Comment: so it would look like:

if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) { 
 
 
 ?>
    <h3>Thank you for your interest in Coastal Pet Products!</h3>
    <p>If you have asked us to contact you, we will be using the information you provided. We thank you for taking the time to help us be a better company.</p>   
 
 <?php } else { ?>
    
     if (mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2) && mail($email_address, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

Comment: @bobkendall I have edited my answer to explain better

Comment: now I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF error

Comment: @bobkendall Please amend your question with your current code that is causing the error, and add the FULL error message, and i will have a look

Comment: the question has been updated the error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /var/www/www.coastalpet.com/htdocs/contact/contact_form_process.php on line 115

Comment: @bobkendall have edited my answer with working code. I really do suggest a book though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the script that sends the mails, as follows:

```
$noResponceDomains = array("aol.com", "more.domain"); // recommended to make a separate config
$domain = end((explode("@", $email))); // $email - user's email
if(!in_array($domain, $noResponceDomains)){
    // send you mail
}
```